# microsoft word header not aligned when the left content is 4 words

Tags: macos, microsoft-word-2011

I want to add header to my document. the header that I want should include two things:

1. The first one is a field for header 1
2. the second one is a static word, which is "Part 1"

Just a side note, i have header for odd pages, and header for even pages, but that has nothing to do with my question)

My problem is when the field for the header 1 is two words, the header becomes extremely perfect, but when the header is 4 words, the two parts are not aligned though there is way much enough space)

The Correct Header:

[image]

The not correct header:

[image]

I am working on mac pro, and this is the version of my word:

```
word:mac 2011
version: 14.5.9 (151119)
```

Edit (added supplementry question from comments):

Why is the left part of the header not aligned with the left margin of the page, while the right part of the header is aligned with the right margin of the page?

Comment: No idea. I haven't used Word for a long time and never on a Mac.

Comment: Answer written as per your request. Comments cleaned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### When the header is 4 words, the two parts are not aligned?

You need to remove a tab from the header style.

---

#### Why is the left part of the header not aligned with the left margin of the page?

This is also an issue with the style. You need to change the **left indent**.

See [Adjust indents and spacing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Adjust-indents-and-spacing-36239d98-14c5-411e-a880-1ddf25d65cd6) and [Indent paragraphs](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Indent-paragraphs-06d6109c-d52e-4e4c-a7b8-697d675b565b) for more information.